# Why did Starfleet not adopt or acquire the Xindi's subspace vortex technology?

Tags: star-trek, ftl-drive, star-trek-enterprise, federation, xindi

In Enterprise, the Xindi used a method of propulsion where they would generate [subspace vortexes](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Subspace_vortex), allowing them to traverse vast distances faster than traditional warp drives.

The Xindi eventually became members of the Federation.

If the Xindi possessed superior FTL drives than that Federation, why was that technology not shared when they joined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> The Xindi were first referenced in Star Trek: The Next Generation
>   episode "The Battle" (the captioning spells them "Xendi," but they
>   were pronounced the same way). This episode was set in the Xendi Sabu
>   star system, as Captain Picard notes in the introductory log entry.
>   Later, Picard receives his old ship the Stargazer, and Data informs
>   the bridge crew that a tug-ship is to take it to Xendi Starbase Nine.

According to Memory Alpha, (and the impression I got while watching the episode), the "Xendi"/Xindi are not currently part of the Federation, as of TNG 1x09:  http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Xendi_Sabu_system

> The Xendi Sabu system was a star system situated close to Federation
>   space and the territory of the Ferengi Alliance.

Comment: According to Memory Alpha, by the 26th century the Xindi are members of the Federation (http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/26th_century).

Comment: @Paperjam And the bulk of the series (TNG/DS9/VOY) take place in the 24th century, so my answer still holds

Comment: of course none of that really explains why the Federation hadn't adapted the technology. Sure, the Xe/indi weren't members but knowing the technology existed would have led federation scientists to pursue it.

Comment: @Izkata Xantec's comment is what I was getting at. It stands to reason that the Federation would have made acquiring the technology a very high priority since an "ally" already possessed it.

Comment: @Paperjam Ah, didn't think of it that way.  However, pretty much any time transwarp technology comes up, the Federation has some sort of problem adapting it. VOY 4x03, for example.  If I had to provide a reason, I'd say that the Federation just hasn't had a scientific breakthrough they need to implement it with their technology.

Comment: That's probably true. I just watched VOY 1x10 "Prime Factors" last night and the technology (spatial trajector) that would have allowed them to instantly transverse over 40,000 lightyears was inherently incompatible with Federation technology.

Comment: @Paperjam after 2-3 hundred years the technology may have been incompatible, but in NX-01 era anything should have been possible as everything was new and there were no pre-existing standards to continue.

Comment: I can't find any reference to this being the case, but is it possible that the portal technology was "loaned" to the Xindi by the Sphere-builders? I also think that retroactively connecting the Xindi from Enterprise to the Xendi from TNG is suspect, canon-wise.

Comment: Technological incompatibility is a temporary problem. It's far easier to fix any technological incompatibility than to discover the actual theoretical knowledge that enables a particular technology to begin with. So it's silly to think that NX-01 era humans would be able to adapt to Xindi technology while being 2-3 centuries more scientifically advanced would prevent it. If anything, it'd be easier since the Federation would have the expertise of far more species and a more diverse range of technologies that have to interoperate with one-another.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Adapt to _what_ Xindi technology?  The Xindi returned to their corner of space, and the superweapon was destroyed.  There was nothing left to study.

Comment: @Izkata: Sorry, that comment was in response to Xantac's suggestion that it would have been easier for NX-01-era Starfleet to adapt their technology to the Xindi's than it would be for 24th century Starfleet. My point was simply that being more scientifically/technological advanced doesn't make it harder for a society to adapt to alien technology.

Comment: @MattPeterson is correct. There's no evidence that Xendi=Xindi other than similar names. Also, as far as I remember the Xendi are never referred to as a race, only places.

Comment: The vortex and weapons technology could have been from the sphere builders

Comment: The impression I got is that the vortexes only work due to the spheres effect on spacetime.